# Getting different values from std::stod() and QString::toDouble() in Qt5

Tags: qt, c++11, floating-point, double

I started a Qt project and linked to it some C++ code I wrote to parse a file. This code is using std::stod() to parse double values, and works fine in a plain c++ project, but when used with a Qt application, std::stod() returns only the integer part of the number.

I wrote and ran some test code, one compiled with g++ 6.1, and the other with qmake 5.6 and the same g++. The results are the same as my projects results.

code compiled with g++ :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  const std::string number("3.14");
  double dbl = std::stod(number);

  std::cout << dbl << '\n'; // 3.14

  return 0;
}
```

It shows the good value : `3.14`

code compiled with Qt :

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const std::string snumber("3.14");
    const QString qnumber = QString::fromStdString("3.14");

    double std_d = std::stod(snumber);
    double qt_d  = qnumber.toDouble();

    qDebug() << std_d << qt_d;                 // 3 3.14
    std::cout << std_d << ' ' << qt_d << '\n'; // 3 3.14

    return a.exec();
}
```

Can you tell me why std::stod() behaves like this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `std::stod` <del>is broken beyond repair and should burn in hell</del> is implemented in terms of `std::strtod`, which interprets doubles **according to the current locale**. QString instead always uses the C locale (use QLocale for locale-specific conversions).

Creating the QCoreApplication instance causes a call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`, which sets the process' locale according to the environment, thus changing `std::stod` behavior.

Comment: Wow, i'd never have thought of that ... i read it in the documentation, but never thought the number formats could be so different between locales. What should i use instead of stod ?

Comment: Well, which (numeric) locale are you under? Under most of European / Russian / South American locales the decimal separator is a comma (','), not a dot ('.'), f.i. `3,14`.

Comment: There's no solution apart from shipping your own `strtod` / `atof` implementation, you can grab Ruby's or FreeBSD's one.

Comment: All my locale variables are set to "fr_FR.utf8" but my LC_ALL is nothing. I wanted to use a dot for decimal separator in my language's grammar. I will just parse numbers with my own function now. Thanks a lot